# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3

Tags: java, stack-overflow, calculator

I'm new to Java and I know there are more posts like this one but I just can't apply them to my code with my current limited understanding of Java. I am using eclipse.exe 
i want this program to work with operators and all kinds of brackets when i type the expression please help me where i got wrong~(sorry that my English is bad)
still have problem with java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
package hww3;
import java.lang.Character.Subset;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("입력: ");
        Calculator cal=new Calculator();

        String susik=s.nextLine();

        System.out.println(susik);
        cal.process(susik);

    }

}
class Calculator{

    public void process(String susik) {
        susik=susik.replaceAll(" ", "");
        double result=calculate(susik);
        System.out.println("="+result);
    }


    private double calculate(String susik) {

        System.out.println(susik);

        double reVal=0;

        if(susik.indexOf("[")!=-1
        ||susik.indexOf("{")!=-1
        ||susik.indexOf("(")!=-1){



            if(susik.indexOf("[")!=-1){
                reVal=calculate(susik,"[","]");
            }

            if(susik.indexOf("{")!=-1){
                reVal=calculate(susik,"{","}");
            }

            if(susik.indexOf("[")!=-1){
                reVal=calculate(susik,"(",")");
            }

        }else{

        if(susik.indexOf("+")!=-1){
                reVal=add(getFirstTerm(susik,"+"),getSecondTerm(susik,"+"));
        }else if(susik.indexOf("-")!=-1){
            reVal=add(getFirstTerm(susik,"-"),getSecondTerm(susik,"-"));
        }else if(susik.indexOf("*")!=-1){
            reVal=add(getFirstTerm(susik,"*"),getSecondTerm(susik,"*"));
        }else if(susik.indexOf("/")!=-1){
            reVal=add(getFirstTerm(susik,"/"),getSecondTerm(susik,"/"));
        }else{
            //연산자가 없을 경우
            reVal=Double.parseDouble(susik);
        }
    }
        return reVal;
}

    private double calculate(String susik, String frontbracket, String endbracket) {

        String frontSusik="";

        String bracketSusik="";

        String endSusik="";

        if(susik.indexOf(frontbracket)!=0){
            frontSusik=susik.substring(0,susik.lastIndexOf(frontbracket));
        }else if(susik.indexOf(endbracket)!=(susik.length()-1)){
            endSusik=susik.substring(susik.lastIndexOf(endSusik));
        }else
        bracketSusik=susik.substring(susik.indexOf(frontbracket)+1,susik.lastIndexOf(endbracket));


        return calculate(frontSusik+calculate(bracketSusik)+endSusik);
    }

    private double getSecondTerm(String susik,String operator){
        return calculate(susik.substring(susik.indexOf(operator)+1));
    }

    private double getFirstTerm(String susik,String operator){
        return calculate(0,susik.substring(susik.indexOf(operator)));
    }
    public double add(double a,double b){
        return a+b;
    }
    public double subtract(double a,double b){
        return a-b;
    }
    public double nultiply(double a,double b){
        return a*b;
    }
    public double divide(double a,double b){
        return a/b;
    }

}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to post the stack trace of the error you are getting, and maybe give more explanation about what parts of your code are doing.

Comment: Your code works fine for me please provide test case for which you are getting SOF Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You substring operation is incorrect for getFirstTerm, you are only passing start index it should from 0 to the index of operator.

try this.

```
    private double getFirstTerm(String susik,String operator){
        return calculate(susik.substring(0,susik.indexOf(operator)));
    }
```

Comment: than u ㅠㅠsooooooooooooooomuch
i dont know why i couldnt see that!!

Comment: Pleas mark this answer as Accepted, if it worked. :)